# Based on culture name from english keyboard how can i type other language in c#

Tags: c#

In C# web application, I have a drop down with culture names and a text box , now based on culture name from drop down i want to enter text in text box in that language only ,

suppose from drop down culture name is selected "de-DE" so when i enter value in text box the value will be in dutch language, But it won't effect the whole application.

Please give some idea how can i work on it.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you the idea of [localization](http://seejoelprogram.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/using-localization-in-aspnet-ajax-part-1-using-localization-in-aspnet/).

This one for the .Net 4.0 [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).